# How to combine the two codes (inserting a table of contents into a project layout)

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, chapters, tocloft, books

> Set up

The layout of my project is this

code 1:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{sectsty,fancyhdr}
\sectionfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}%remove 





% *******************************Margin Settings*******************************

\geometry{% margin settings, has to go first before \pagestyle{}
paper=a4paper, 
inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
outer=2.5cm, % Outer margin
bindingoffset=0.0cm, % Binding offset
top=2.5cm, % Top margin
bottom=2.5cm, % Bottom margin
headsep=4.5mm,% controles header  
footskip=7.4mm,% controles footer
%showframe,% show how the type block is set on the page
}

% ***************************Header/Footer Settings****************************

 \sectionfont{\LARGE\bfseries}%this will keep the formattings of sections
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets all head and foot elements empty.
\rhead{} % right side of upper footer 
\lhead{Project title} %left side 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2.0pt} % Width of the top line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.0pt} % Bottom line 
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}%used to remove the \fancyhf{} \headheight error
\rfoot{Page \thepage} % vice versa with the page number 
\lfoot{\leftmark} % Should show the name of section 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%this avoids the \makecaptical of footers
    \markboth{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\z@ %this allowes symbols in foorters
  \thesection\hskip 1em\relax
\fi #1}{}}
\makeatother

% ***************************title Settings****************************


\newcommand{\mytitle}{

\begin{center}
{\Huge{\textbf{Project of...}}} 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
 \textsc{\Large My name}\\[0.5cm] 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
{\large My ID number}\\[0.5cm] 
\end{center}

}


% ********************************NEW CHAPTER PAGE SETTING*********************
\fancypagestyle{chapterstart}{% 1st page of the chapters, i.e. no new page for chapter
}
\makeatletter

\def\chapter{
\pagestyle{chapterstart}
\secdef\@chapter\@schapter}


 \renewcommand\thesection{\@arabic\c@section} 


 \makeatother
% ********************************CHAPTER STYLE SETTING***********************
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}%**change
\usepackage{titlesec, color} %remove blindtext after
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75} %1=white, 0=black
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}} %spacing between line and text
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\vspace*{-2em}\Huge\bfseries}{\scalebox{1}    {\thechapter}\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{} %spacing across entire page     %CHANGES** \scalebox{2}{}**3pt, **\vspace{+ down - up}
    \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{30pt} %change{right}{shift down}{tile and text}

 %------------------------------------------------------------------

 % Begin Project

 %------------------------------------------------------------------

 \begin{document}

 %-------------------------------Title-------------------------------
 \mytitle

 %------------------------------Begin--------------------------------

 \chapter{Minor introduction}
 \section{Introduction}
 \subsection{Super introduction}
 \lipsum[4-11]%remove

 \newpage 
 \chapter{Something more}
 \section{ssection 1}
 \subsection{subection 1}
 \lipsum

 \newpage 
 \chapter*{Appendix}
 \section*{section}
 \lipsum

 \newpage 
 \chapter*{Bibliography}
 \lipsum




  %------------------------------------------------------------------

  % end Project

  %------------------------------------------------------------------ 


  \end{document}
```

[image]

The table of contents I want is this

code 2:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\renewcommand\contentsname{CONTENTS}
\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
\addtocontents{toc}{{\bfseries Contents\hfill Page No.\bigskip\par}}
\addtocontents{lot}{{\bfseries No.\hfill Title\hfill\hfill Page No.\bigskip\par}}
\addtocontents{lof}{{\bfseries No.\hfill Title\hfill\hfill Page No.\bigskip\par}}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor,xpatch}
\renewcommand\cftbeforechapskip{0ex}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{: }
\newlength\tocindent
\settowidth\tocindent{\cftchapfont\cftchappresnum9\cftchapaftersnum}
\edef\cftchapnumwidth{\the\tocindent}
\edef\cftsecindent{\the\tocindent}
\advance\tocindent2.3em
\edef\cftsubsecindent{\the\tocindent}
\advance\tocindent3.2em
\edef\cftsubsubsecindent{\the\tocindent}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecdotsep{\cftnodots}
\newcommand\tocmainmatter
  {\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\color{white}}%
  }
    \xapptocmd\mainmatter{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\tocmainmatter}}{}{}


\newif\ifschaptertoc
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makeschapterhead[1]%
 {{\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
  \ifschaptertoc
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  \fi
 }
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

%dots
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for sections
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for subsection




%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\schaptertoctrue

%------------------------------------
\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
\blindtext
%------------------------------------
\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
\blindtext
%------------------------------------
\listoftables

\listoffigures
%------------------------------------
\chapter*{ABBREVIATIONS}
\Blindtext
%------------------------------------
\chapter*{NOTATIONS}
\Blindtext

\mainmatter
%------------------------------------
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\blindtext
%************************************
\section{General Background}
\blindtext

  \section{Objective}
\blindtext
\subsection{Objective 1}
\blindtext
\subsection{Objective 2}
\blindtext
\subsection{Objective 3}
\blindtext

\section{Scheme}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Goal

How do I combine the two codes?

I.e. How do I put the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables from code 2 into code 1. I tried by copying code 2 into code 1, and then using \include{code 2}, but the formatting for the table came out very badly. (the word "contents" did not line with the text, and all number were in roman numerals)

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want, but have you tried `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+V`?

Comment: No I copied the preambles into a separate .tex file and used \include{} to insert it into the main. I removed the packages which were duplicates, but some formatting errors came out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the preamble of code 2 into the preamble of code 1 (here I did this right before `begin{document}`). Then some clean up is required. You must check the packages loaded for potential conflicts. In your case only the packages `color` (code 1) and `xcolor` (code 2) are an issue. But this is easy to solve, because `xcolor` is basically an extended version of `color`, so only load `xcolor`.

With other documents you would also have to throw out everything not needed for formatting the table of contents. But (besides `blindtext`) there is nothing in code 2.

The header for the toc (Contents   Page No.) is treated as a normal paragraph and therefore indendented by `\parindent`. This can be removed with `\noindent` added to the `\addtocontents` line, but it must be `\protect`ed.

A part of the code 2 preamble centers the headline for `\chapter*`. This centers **Contents** but also **Appendix** and **Bibliography**. By commenting out this code (I marked it in the source) you get back to left aligned headlines.

**Edit:**

This code also adds `\chapter*` headlines to the TOC, if you set `\schaptertoctrue` after `\tableofcontents` (set before would also add a line for the TOC to the TOC). You can disable this with `\schaptertocfalse` before the `\chpter*` you don`t want in the TOC.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{sectsty,fancyhdr}
\sectionfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}%remove 

% *******************************Margin Settings*******************************

\geometry{% margin settings, has to go first before \pagestyle{}
paper=a4paper, 
inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
outer=2.5cm, % Outer margin
bindingoffset=0.0cm, % Binding offset
top=2.5cm, % Top margin
bottom=2.5cm, % Bottom margin
headsep=4.5mm,% controles header  
footskip=7.4mm,% controles footer
%showframe,% show how the type block is set on the page
}

% ***************************Header/Footer Settings****************************

 \sectionfont{\LARGE\bfseries}%this will keep the formattings of sections
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets all head and foot elements empty.
\rhead{} % right side of upper footer 
\lhead{Project title} %left side 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2.0pt} % Width of the top line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.0pt} % Bottom line 
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}%used to remove the \fancyhf{} \headheight error
\rfoot{Page \thepage} % vice versa with the page number 
\lfoot{\leftmark} % Should show the name of section 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%this avoids the \makecaptical of footers
    \markboth{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\z@ %this allowes symbols in foorters
  \thesection\hskip 1em\relax
\fi #1}{}}
\makeatother

% ***************************title Settings****************************

\newcommand{\mytitle}{

\begin{center}
{\Huge{\textbf{Project of...}}} 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
 \textsc{\Large My name}\\[0.5cm] 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
{\large My ID number}\\[0.5cm] 
\end{center}

}

% ********************************NEW CHAPTER PAGE SETTING*********************
\fancypagestyle{chapterstart}{% 1st page of the chapters, i.e. no new page for chapter
}
\makeatletter

\def\chapter{
\pagestyle{chapterstart}
\secdef\@chapter\@schapter}

 \renewcommand\thesection{\@arabic\c@section} 

 \makeatother
% ********************************CHAPTER STYLE SETTING***********************
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}%**change
% replace color by xcolor (both are for color support, but xcolor is used in code 2 preamble)
\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor} %remove blindtext after
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75} %1=white, 0=black
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}} %spacing between line and text
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\vspace*{-2em}\Huge\bfseries}{\scalebox{1}    {\thechapter}\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{} %spacing across entire page     %CHANGES** \scalebox{2}{}**3pt, **\vspace{+ down - up}
    \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{30pt} %change{right}{shift down}{tile and text}

 %------------------------------------------------------------------

 %- preamble from code 2 -------------------------------------------

\renewcommand\contentsname{CONTENTS}
\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
% added \protect\noindent to remove \parindent from table header
\addtocontents{toc}{{\protect\noindent\bfseries Contents\hfill Page No.\bigskip\par}}
\addtocontents{lot}{{\protect\noindent\bfseries No.\hfill Title\hfill\hfill Page No.\bigskip\par}}
\addtocontents{lof}{{\protect\noindent\bfseries No.\hfill Title\hfill\hfill Page No.\bigskip\par}}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
% xcolor removed, because it's loaded above
\usepackage{xpatch}
\renewcommand\cftbeforechapskip{0ex}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{: }
\newlength\tocindent
\settowidth\tocindent{\cftchapfont\cftchappresnum9\cftchapaftersnum}
\edef\cftchapnumwidth{\the\tocindent}
\edef\cftsecindent{\the\tocindent}
\advance\tocindent2.3em
\edef\cftsubsecindent{\the\tocindent}
\advance\tocindent3.2em
\edef\cftsubsubsecindent{\the\tocindent}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecdotsep{\cftnodots}
\newcommand\tocmainmatter
  {\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\color{white}}%
  }
    \xapptocmd\mainmatter{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\tocmainmatter}}{}{}

% centers \chapter* headers
% if unwanted comment out ...
\newif\ifschaptertoc
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makeschapterhead[1]%
 {{\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
  \ifschaptertoc
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  \fi
 }
\makeatother
% ... to here

%\usepackage{blindtext} thrown out, one dummy text package is enough

%dots
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for sections
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for subsection

 %------------------------------------------------------------------

 % Begin Project

 %------------------------------------------------------------------

 \begin{document}
% \mainmatter

 \tableofcontents
 \schaptertoctrue % enable adding \chapter* headlines to the TOC

 %-------------------------------Title-------------------------------
 \mytitle

 %------------------------------Begin--------------------------------

 \chapter{Minor introduction}
 \section{Introduction}
 \subsection{Super introduction}
 \lipsum[4-11]%remove

 \newpage 
 \chapter{Something more}
 \section{ssection 1}
 \subsection{subection 1}
 \lipsum

 %\schaptertocfalse % to disable adding \chapter* headline to the TOC
 \newpage 
 \chapter*{Appendix}
 \section*{section}
 \lipsum

 \newpage 
 \chapter*{Bibliography}
 \lipsum




  %------------------------------------------------------------------

  % end Project

  %------------------------------------------------------------------ 


  \end{document}
```

**Edit: Roman page numbers:**

This is due to `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` in code 2 after `\begin{document}` (there is also `\backmatter`). `\frontmatter` sets lower case roman page numbering. Usually it's followed by abstract, TOC, LOF, LOT, and other stuff, which isn't the main contents of your document. The latter follows after `\mainmatter`, which sets the page numbering to arabic and resets the page number. So the first page of your document is page i and chapter 1 is on page 1. Without these commands `\mainmatter` is asumed, the first page of the document is page 1 and chapter 1 is on some higher numbered page. Note: this may require three latex runs, until everything is correct.

Comment: "The header for the toc (Contents Page No.) is treated as a normal paragraph" Thanks so much, this makes sense, I was trying to figure out what went wrong. Any idea how code 2 got `\chapter*{}`, `\listoftables`, and ` \listoffigures` to be included in the TOC using roman numerals? (look at image above)

Comment: @UniStuffz: I added the answer to this to my answer (it was a bit to long for a comment.

Comment: Okay Final question, so I've added the numbering difference to my own code, and it makes sense `\fontmatter` for numbering before chapter 1, `\mainmatter` after and `\backmatter` for the appendix and things. However the appendix, LOF, LOT still aren't listed in the TOC just like code 2, any ideas?

Comment: @UniStuffz: and another edit to also cover this.